# onDragEvent() throwing nullpointer on Nexus

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-event

I am sorry if I have done any silly mistake, but I cant find the source of this:
I am trying to implement a onDrag listener on my EditText "etItem"
This is my code:

```
 etItem.setOnDragListener(new OnDragListener(){

            @Override
            public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent dragevent) {

                if(null!=dragevent && null!=v){

                    if( dragevent.getAction() == DragEvent.ACTION_DROP )
                    {
                      View view = (View) dragevent.getLocalState();
                      ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();

                      int itemNum = (Integer) view.getTag();
                      itemAmounts[itemNum] = 0;
                      owner.removeView(view);
                      return true;

                    }
                    }
                return false;
            }});
```

This is working fine on my Samsng Galaxy Grand, But giving me a nullpointer on Nexus.

The stackTrace:

```
03-26 15:47:21.185: E/AndroidRuntime(1439): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-26 15:47:21.185: E/AndroidRuntime(1439): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-26 15:47:21.185: E/AndroidRuntime(1439):     at android.widget.Editor.onDrop(Editor.java:1797)
03-26 15:47:21.185: E/AndroidRuntime(1439):     at android.widget.TextView.onDragEvent(TextView.java:8350)
03-26 15:47:21.185: E/AndroidRuntime(1439):     at android.view.View.dispatchDragEvent(View.java:16375)
03-26 15:47:21.185: E/AndroidRuntime(1439):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1237)
03-26 15:47:21.185: E/AndroidRuntime(1439):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1237)
03-26 15:47:21.185: E/AndroidRuntime(1439):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1237)
03-26 15:47:21.185: E/AndroidRuntime(1439):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1237)
03-26 15:47:21.185: E/AndroidRuntime(1439):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1237)
03-26 15:47:21.185: E/AndroidRuntime(1439):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1237)
03-26 15:47:21.185: E/AndroidRuntime(1439):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1237)
03-26 15:47:21.185: E/AndroidRuntime(1439):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1237)
03-26 15:47:21.185: E/AndroidRuntime(1439):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1237)
03-26 15:47:21.185: E/AndroidRuntime(1439):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleDragEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3838)
03-26 15:47:21.185: E/AndroidRuntime(1439):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.access$600(ViewRootImpl.java:95)
03-26 15:47:21.185: E/AndroidRuntime(1439):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2999)
03-26 15:47:21.185: E/AndroidRuntime(1439):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-26 15:47:21.185: E/AndroidRuntime(1439):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-26 15:47:21.185: E/AndroidRuntime(1439):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
03-26 15:47:21.185: E/AndroidRuntime(1439):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-26 15:47:21.185: E/AndroidRuntime(1439):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-26 15:47:21.185: E/AndroidRuntime(1439):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-26 15:47:21.185: E/AndroidRuntime(1439):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-26 15:47:21.185: E/AndroidRuntime(1439):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-26 15:47:21.345: W/ActivityManager(297):   Force finishing activity com.listcalc.main/.MainActivityFree
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is a bug with `EditText` widgets and the Drag and Drop API in Android. I added a post to the issue tracker linked in the other solution, but I'll reproduce it here for easy reading. If you experience this problem, **[please go to the tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=21775) though and star** the issue to hopefully make the Android engineers aware of it (wishful thinking, I know).

### Cause of crash

I came across this crash/bug in 4.4.2 while trying to use the Drag and Drop API to move an `EditText` around in a `FrameLayout` (very simple goal). I only have an `OnDragListener` set on my `FrameLayout`, but apparently the framework calls all the children `View`'s `OnDragEvent()` callbacks as can be seen in the crash stacktrace.

The crash occurs in the internal Class `android.widget.Editor.onDrop()` where the method tries to access `ClipData` info from the `DragEvent` that is passed to the method.

**[From 4.4.2 source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/widget/Editor.java#Editor.onDrop%28android.view.DragEvent%29):**

```
1828    void onDrop(DragEvent event) {
1829        StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder("");
1830        ClipData clipData = event.getClipData();
1831        final int itemCount = clipData.getItemCount();
1832        for (int i=0; i < itemCount; i++) {
1833            Item item = clipData.getItemAt(i);
1834            content.append(item.coerceToStyledText(mTextView.getContext()));
1835        }
            ....
```

In line 1830 `event.getClipData()` returns `null`. Then in line 1831 `clipData.getItemCount()` will trigger an NPE. This only seems to happen with `EditText`'s since they have a `android.widget.Editor` instance field, which leads me to think this is a bug/oversight.

I found two workarounds for this.

### First workaround:

Similar to the workaround proposed in comment #1, you can set a dummy `OnDragListener` on your `EditText` objects that are in the hierarchy of Views that will receive Drag events. However, the dummy listener can simply be

```
myEditText.setOnDragListener( new View.OnDragListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onDrag( View v, DragEvent event) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

By just returning `true` for all Drag events you'll be telling the framework you've handled the event no matter what the type of Action was (i.e. the action you get from calling `event.getAction()`). This means you'll intercept the Drag event and it won't be passed any further to the View's actual `OnDragEvent()` callback, therefore avoiding the crash that we see in the stacktrace.

It's not necessary to have a separate condition for `(event.getAction() == DragEvent.ACTION_DROP)` as seen in comment #1 for this dummy listener, since if you return false for `ACTION_DRAG_STARTED` you'll never receive the `ACTION_DROP` event anyway (you can confirm this by placing a Log print message in the `ACTION_DROP` condition and you'll notice it never gets called because you already returned `false` in the `else` condition).

### Second workaround: *EDITED (see below)

Since the NPE occurs when trying to access `null` `ClipData` in `Editor.onDrop()`, you can simply provide a dummy `ClipData` to the `DragEvent` when you begin the dragging process.

This is how I did it for my scenario:

```
... <other code>
ClipData dummyData = ClipData.newPlainText("dummyData", ""); // don't forget to pass empty String
DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(v);
v.startDrag(dummyData, shadowBuilder, v, 0);
...
```

I chose to use the helper method `ClipData.newPlainText` to just create a simple plain text `ClipData` for me since you can't just construct a `ClipData` with its constructors and `null` parameters because that will lead to crashes also.

So where ever it was you begin your drag process with `View.startDrag()` be sure to provide this dummy `ClipData`. With this workaround I don't need the dummy `OnDragListener` and I don't get any NPE crashes.

**NOTE:** if you use the first workaround, know that by returning `true` from the dummy `OnDragListener` you'll effectively stop the DragEvent from propagating to `TextView.onDragEvent()` so none of the code that lives in there will be called. I'm unsure of the side-effects of this if any, but it's definitely not an empty method.

***EDIT:** Upon playing around with Drag and Drop with `EditText` widgets some more, I discovered that there's some really weird behavior with `TextView.onDragEvent()` which is what eventually gets called if you go with the **second workaround**. I noticed that when using the dummy `ClipData` that I suggested, the "*dummyData*" string that you pass as the second argument to `ClipData.newPlainText()` will sometimes get pasted/inserted into the `EditText` if you try to drag the widget around a bit while also moving the caret within the text box, or by typing into the `EditText` and then dragging it after.

It's very confusing to explain, but I was able to reproduce it reliably. Any readers can [**take a look at the source code**](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/widget/TextView.java#TextView.onDragEvent%28android.view.DragEvent%29) for the method if they want to try and make sense of it, but I'm honestly tired of trying to figure out the weird intentions the Android Engineers had for this. Because of this odd behavior I altered my second workaround to pass an empty String as the second argument instead. This seems to alleviate the problem.

Personally I ended up extending the `EditText` class and making my own and simply overriding `onDragEvent()` to `return true;` and not call through to the superclass (i.e. `TextView.onDragEvent()`. This is in essence the same as **First workaround** but I needed to extend the `EditText` class anyway to add some extra functionality. Whatever the original code in `TextView.onDragEvent()` does, skipping it doesn't seem to affect my personal use case and I don't notice any lack of functionality that I needed.

Comment: Dummy data fixed my problem, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

NVM, found the issue.
Turns out its probably a bug in the framework.

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=21775

reports the same problem with nexus.